# android unsupported encoding exception

Tags: android, rest, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using commons-httpclient.
In my android code as given below, the StringRequestEntity always throws and exception of Unsupported Encoding Exception. But above code works fine when execute from inside a java code. But gives exception error in android code. Here are the imports

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity;
```

code snippet

```
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                PostMethod method = new PostMethod(URL);
                StringBuffer requestContent = new StringBuffer();

                RequestObject requestObject = new RequestObject();
                requestObject.setMobileNo("9999999999");

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                requestContent.append(gson.toJson(requestObject));
                String requestContentString = requestContent.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "Request = " + requestContentString);

                RequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity(requestContentString, "application/text", URL);

            } 
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```